# wrap three nested for loops into recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, combinations

I have a method that returns all possible combinations of 3 elements in a given string.

```
void FindAllCombinationsBy3(string &str, int start)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i++)
    {
       for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length() - 1; j++)
       {
          for (int k = j + 1; k < str.length(); k++)
          {
             cout << str[i] << str[j] << str[k] << endl;
          }
       }
    }

    return;
}
```

It works fine and outputs this: abc abd abe abf acd ace acf ade. But I want to write a recursive version of the method that will receive a parameter n of combinations length. So not just 3, but a custom length. It should probably look something like this. But I just got lost with this recursion conditions.

```
void FindAllCombinationsByNValues(string &str, int start, int depth, int n)
{
   if (depth++ >= n)
   {    
      return;
   }

   for (int i = start; i < str.length() - n + depth; i++)
   {
      cout << str[i];
      FindAllCombinationsByNValues(str, start + 1, depth, n);
   }

   cout << endl;
}
```

I know that this were asked a million times but other solution didn`t help yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void print_combinations(const std::string& s, unsigned n, unsigned j = 0, const std::string& a = "") {
  if (n == 0) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
  } else {
    for (auto i = j; i < s.length() - (n - 1); ++i) {
      print_combinations(s, n - 1, i + 1, a + s[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
print_combinations("abcde", 3);
```

Output:

```
abc
abd
abe
acd
ace
ade
bcd
bce
bde
cde
```

Comment: i was close at some point, but didn`t accumulate characters as you did. it helped